# Setting Variant to collection item always returns an error

Tags: vba, excel

### Context

I have a custom function, whose scope is to take in input a certain range of values (that is a list of *possibly duplicate* strings such as `"EUR/USD"`, `"USD/BRL"`, `"EUR/USD"` and output a SQL-like string like the following:

```
not in ('EUR/USD', 'USD/BRL' ... )
```

Since the values in the spreadsheet might be duplicated, before to do any parsing I'm trying to create a collection of unique values (for example, if `EUR/USD` appears 4 times in the spreadsheet, I only want it to be in my collection once).

In order to reach this purpose, I have developed this simple function:

```
Public Function NOT_IN_SQL(ByVal values As Range) As String

    'parse list (get uniques only)
    Dim uniquesCollection As New Collection
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In values

        If Not inCollection(uniquesCollection, rng.Value) Then
            uniquesCollection.Add rng.Value
        End If

    Next rng

    NOT_IN_SQL = "tmp crap value"

End Function
```

As you can notice, the `If` block deciding whether adding a certain value to the collection or not is using another custom function, `inCollection`, defined as follows:

```
Private Function inCollection(ByVal coll As Collection, ByVal element As String) As Boolean

    Dim var As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
        var = coll.Item(element)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            inCollection = False
        Else
            inCollection = True
        End If
        Set var = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

This function is basically trying to set the object `var` (declared as `Variant`) as the `collection.Item()` with index the value of the currently analyzed range.

If an error is raised, it means the element was not found in the collection so I return `inCollection = False`, otherwise I return `True` [I know it's not a nice way to implement, but it's the best try-catch approach I can think of in VBA].

### Problem

However, it seems I'm having an issue with my code of the second function. 
In fact, no matter if the element is or is not in the collection, the statement:

```
var = coll.Item(element)
```

will always raise an exception, so it will never tell me if the element is or not in the collection.

### Test/debug case

1) Open an Excel spreadsheet, add a Module and copy/paste the two above functions

2) In the ranges A1 and A2 of any spreadsheet, type the values `test` and `test` (same values).

3) In the range A3 insert `=NOT_IN_SQL(A1:A2)` in debug mode and add a watcher to the object `uniquesCollection` to see what it looks like at the end of the function. You will see that it's `("test","test")` even if I would have expected only `("test")`.

Please note: I already made a first analysis and, as stated above, the problem is that `var = coll.Item(element)` is *always* raising an exception (so `inCollection` always returns `False`), but I don't understand why.

Could anyone please help me to understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use key when you add the items to collection. ```Collection.Add (item, key, before, after)```.

Comment: @dee Stated as optional argument. But well, it's needed in this case :)

Comment: But if you don't use the key, you can't match on the key in your second routine. Personally I'd just use an in-line OERN, add to the collection, then OEG0 rather than a separate function. Or use a Dictionary.

Comment: @dee, thanks, I had never used collections with keys (thought in VBA I had to use dictionaries for that, while collections were with element = key) so I didn't know I could add the element along with a separate key. Could you please write is an answer so I'm going to accept it?

Comment: Ok, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `NOT_IN_SQL` the key needs to be used when item is added to the collection.

```
Dim uniquesCollection As Collection
Dim rng As Range
Dim value

Set uniquesCollection = New Collection

For Each rng In values
    If Not IsError(rng.value) Then
        value = Trim(rng.value)
        If value <> "" Then
            If Not inCollection(uniquesCollection, value) Then
                uniquesCollection.Add value, value
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next rng
```

See [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265006(v=vs.60).aspx) method documentation.